# Using `void main` in D

Tags: d

I've seen D code that uses `void main`. Is this legal? If yes, is returning non-`void` (`int`) also legal? Why is this allowed in the language?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888661/how-can-d-return-0-on-success-and-non-zero-on-failure-if-main-is-void

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [D Language Reference](http://www.d-programming-language.org/function.html)

> main() Func­tion
>
> For con­sole pro­grams, main() serves as the entry point. It gets called after all the mod­ule ini­tial­iz­ers are run, and after any unittests are run. After it re­turns, all the mod­ule destruc­tors are run. main() must be de­clared using one of the fol­low­ing forms:

```
void main() { ... }
void main(char[][] args) { ... }
int main() { ... }
int main(char[][] args) { ... }
```

So `void main` is legal.

From the same docs, [return statement](http://www.d-programming-language.org/statement.html#ReturnStatement) part:

> A re­turn exits the cur­rent func­tion and sup­plies its re­turn value. Ex­pres­sion is re­quired if the func­tion spec­i­fies a re­turn type that is not void. The Ex­pres­sion is im­plic­itly con­verted to the func­tion re­turn type

So it appears that returning something from a void function is not explicitly disallowed (and indeed doing so compiles fine).

(Why would you want to do that though?)

Comment: Addendum: when `void main` ends, D exits with 0. When `main` exits by exception, the runtime exits with an appropriate error code. Not returning a value from a non-void function is not allowed, and will error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The following versions of the `main()` function are legal:

```
void main() { ... }
void main(char[][] args) { ... }
int main() { ... }
int main(char[][] args) { ... }
```

The `void main` versions are the same as the `int main` versions, if they always return 0 or throw.